# How to handle errors thrown within compute?

Tags: flutter

My questions is specific to Flutter's top level function `compute` (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute-constant.html)

What is the recommended way to handle errors?

Example:

```dart
String expensiveSyncFunction(int x) {
  // Can an error thrown here ...
  throw Error();
}

void getResult() async {

  // ... be caught here.
  await compute(expensiveSyncFunction, 10);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try-catch, no?

```
  void getResult() async {
    try {
      await compute(expensiveSyncFunction, 10);
    } catch(e, stacktrace) {
      // caught here
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, absolutely. It works ! Thank you. (Coming to think of it, not sure why I had the question in the first.)